# Does an expenses-paid interview cover meals as well?

Tags: interviewing, travel, expenses

This is for a position in the US. The company is paying for the flight, cab, hotel expenses. The domestic flight is over 4 hours each way. Can I also claim the food expense during my travel and stay. The company provides an expense reimbursement form. Obviously, no alcohol, but how much is good for meal expense?

Comment: You can look up "Per Diem Rates" for whatever area you will be staying in, and it will tell you the standard daily allowance for that geographic area.  For example, the [US Gov](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/content/104877) has established a daily per diem of $89 per day for the state of Maine.

Comment: @Lumberjack the $89 is for the hotel, the rate for meals and incidentals is $51. Some cities are higher.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Of course you are right.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Why was my comment deleted?

Comment: @EdHeal, Most of us don't have access to deleted comments. What did your comment say anyway? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the comments, if you want chapter and verse on corporate policy for your prospective employer you will need to ask them.

If you're just trying to find out what a reasonable person would expense for dining in their local area without wanting to make them think you're planning to 'soak' the expense account, I would suggest asking your Interview contacts if there's any place they'd recommend and/or that they know the company uses for entertaining.

Comment: Asking for a place they recommend is actually a very good advice

Comment: @mjsarfatti might improve the quality of the meal as well of course if it's from a place locals recommend

Comment: @RobM and it might be a good chance to build a rapport with your potential new employer.